# Calculate field based in two ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am trying to develop a web app in Django. I have two ajax requests in an HTML template that are working well, but when I try to calculate a field and put it on another field (#minherente), this calculate the field with the previously value, but not with the values got in two ajax. I'll appreciate your help.

```
$("#id_Falla").change(function () {
  var url = $("#MatrizForm").attr("data-fi-url"); 
  var FallaId = $("#id_Falla").val();  
  var url1 = $("#MatrizForm").attr("data-ii-url"); 

  $.ajax({                     
    url: url,                  
    data: {
      'Falla': FallaId      
    },
    success: function (data) {   
      $("#finherente").val(data);

    }
  });
  $.ajax({                      
    url: url1,                 
    data: {
      'Falla': FallaId      
    },
    success: function (data1) {  
      $("#iinherente").val(data1);  
    }

  });

  var frecuencia = $('#finherente').val();
  var impacto = $('#iinherente').val();

  $('#minherente').val(frecuencia*impacto);
});
```

Any help would be most appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the ajax requests are asynchronous, you cannot depend on the data being resolved outside of the callback. Only inside of the success callback you can make sure the data is resolved.

You could just make one request after another by nesting them, and only when both have resolved, you will have access to the data:

```js
$("#id_Falla").change(function () {
  var url = $("#MatrizForm").attr("data-fi-url");
  var FallaId = $("#id_Falla").val();
  var url1 = $("#MatrizForm").attr("data-ii-url");

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
      'Falla': FallaId
    },
    success: function (frecuencia) {
      $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        data: {
          'Falla': FallaId
        },
        success: function (impacto) {
          $("#finherente").val(frecuencia);
          $("#iinherente").val(impacto);  
          $('#minherente').val(frecuencia * impacto);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If you want to process both requests concurrently, you could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) since jQuery works with promises out of the box:

```js
$("#id_Falla").change(function () {
  var url = $("#MatrizForm").attr("data-fi-url");
  var FallaId = $("#id_Falla").val();
  var url1 = $("#MatrizForm").attr("data-ii-url");

  Promise.all([
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
        'Falla': FallaId
      },
    }),
    $.ajax({
      url: url1,
      data: {
        'Falla': FallaId
      },
    }),
  ]).then(([frecuencia, impacto]) => {
    $("#finherente").val(frecuencia);
    $("#iinherente").val(impacto);  
    $('#minherente').val(frecuencia * impacto);
  });
});
```

Alternatively, consider using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of jQuery's `$.ajax`.